# How to Unit Test errors in Python when using Try and Except

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I'm trying to unit test one of my functions to ensure that the database connection is valid, and if it's not, raise the proper exception.I'm having difficulty in being able to test if the proper exception was raised given that the database connection is **not** valid

I've successfully mocked the database connection and get the result I want when the connection is valid. However, despite the test being successful, it is definitely not working as intended. When I mock the database connection with a specific error and assert that a different error was raised the test still passes even though they are different errors. See code for more details.

```
def get_database():
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(
            r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
            r'DBQ=M:\Path\To\Database\My_Database.accdb;'
        )
        return conn
    # I want to assert this specific error is raised given bad connection
    except pyodbc.Error as err: 
        raise err

@mock.patch('directory1.script1.pyodbc.connect')
def test_database_connection_error(self, mock_conn):

        # If connection is valid test works as intended!
        get_database()
        mock_conn.assert_called_once_with((
            r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
            r'DBQ=M:\Path\To\Database\My_Database.accdb;'
        ))

        # This test still passes even though the errors are different!
        mock_conn.side_effect = pyodbc.ProgrammingError
        self.assertRaises(pyodbc.Error, get_database)
```

I expect that if the mock database connection is set to one type of error and another error is asserted than the test should fail. This is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyodbc.ProgrammingError` is a subclass of `pyodbc.DatabaseError`, which is a subclass of `pyodbc.Error`, so with your:

```
self.assertRaises(pyodbc.Error, get_database)
```

it would pass as long as any exception instance of a subclass of `pyodbc.Error`, including `pyodbc.DatabaseError`, is raised.

You should be specific about which subclass of `pyodbc.Error` you want to catch instead.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I assume you might be familiar with pyodbc? The error I'm looking to catch is when the database path doesn't exist (i.e the database is deleted, moved etc.). When I run the function with the wrong path I get this long winded traceback that is really unhelpful. It's so long that I can't even fit it to post it here, but the start of it goes:

pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x2078 Thread 0x3f24 DBC 0xa2680b4. Not sure which subclass I'm looking for...

Comment: Glad to be of help. Unfortunately I don't know about the specific error you're describing here. You'd be better off posting this issue as a new question with proper tags so that more people with the right knowledge can help.